# Run function after setting state with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to run a function with a countdown after updating state with hooks after an API call, but I'm having a hard time because the state is not updated yet. Using `useEffect` with `setInterval` is also not working because it creates many instances of set interval which brakes everything.

```
 async function fetchData() {
    const res = await fetch(API);
    res.json()
        .then(res => {
            setTime(res);

        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))  

}

const setTime = (data) => {
    const obj = Time(data);
    setDays(obj.day)
    setHours(obj.hour)
    setMinutes(obj.minute);
    setSeconds(obj.second);


 useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, []); 

useEffect(() => {
    runClock();
}, [seconds]) //I understand why it happens since it will run useEffect every time seconds changes

function runClock() {
    let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(seconds+ "seconds")
       if(seconds > 0){
            setSeconds(prevSeconds => prevSeconds -1);
       }
// more logic...
}
```

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible or if I just need another approach? And for reference, I'm making a countdown timer.

Comment: Maybe you can create a different `useEffect()` where you have in the dependency array the awaited variable or state for the change.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that actually worked. I didn't use an array or made another `useEffect()` But Same idea.

 I just made a "dummy" hook and updated after I fetched the API and made it dependent of that same `useEffect()` that was dependent of seconds. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setInterval and bring all the logic inside the `runClock()` function to the useEffect which has the dependency of seconds. Then you collect the interval id into a variable and then after which you implement a cleanup function to do away with the timeout. as such when next the effect is being run it will set a new one. that way you won't run into too many instances of setInterval

to do that you should return a function from your effect that clears the interval.

```
useEffect(() => {
     let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(seconds+ "seconds")
       if(seconds > 0){
            setSeconds(prevSeconds => prevSeconds -1);
       }
// more logic...
      }
    return clearInterval(intervalId)
}, [seconds])
```

More about [useEffects here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: It didn't work. It now decreases by 20 every second.